# ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector

I am using C# on vs 2010 and i am trying to use Entity Framework 5. My database is in MySQL and i use the provided connector.

When i use entity model table in order to read, i get this exception message. 
Maybe there are also other questions like that but i cannot find the solution.

My code is similar to this:

```
    using (Entities model = new Entities())
        {

            handler h = model.handlers.Find(0);  //here i get the exception
            Console.Out.WriteLine(h.device_name);


        }
```

In my packages.config file i read the following xml code:

```
    <packages>
        <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
    </packages>
```

Should i do a kind of configuration setup in the this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found what was wrong.

I had to use the correct MySQL connector.

The question is closed!